# When does 今に refer to?

Tags: meaning

On jisho.org, the definition of 今に is given as "before long; even now" and 今にも is given as "at any time; soon" so the both seem to refer to the near future with 今にも perhaps being more immediate.  However, example sentences I've seen seem to give no indication that 今に is referring to a near future.  E.g., also from jisho.org:

> 今に後悔するぞ。 You will yet regret it.
>
> 今にわかる。   You'll see.
>
> 今にバチがあたるぞ。　You'll get it someday.

Does 今に indicate a near future?  If not, why is 今 used in this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「[今]{いま}に」 surely means "***in the near future***" said in the speaker's **inference** or **volition**.  A synonym would be 「そのうち」.

In all of your three example sentences, 「今に」 is used that way.  If it did not feel like it, it would be because of the liberty taken in the translations.

Not that I did not know it before, jisho is not such a good dictionary if it just says 「今に」 means "before long; even now" because "even now" is the literary usage of 「今に」.  It is rarely used for that meaning in one's everyday kind of conversation.